# How load private Amazon S3 files with javascript?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-s3

I have a difficult problem:

I am using **OpenSeadragon** for viewing large photos on my private Laravel webapplication.
The photos and tiles are stored in my private Amazon S3 bucket.

But how can I access this private photos in my javascript OpenSeadragon component in a safe what?

What I have done: I created a router function in my Laravel application that redirects to Amazon S3:

```
function getTiles($tile) {
  // validation && authorisation
  return redirect()->to(\Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($tile, now()->addMinutes(5)));
}
```

And I have configured my OpenSeadragon component (according https://openseadragon.github.io/examples/tilesource-custom/) so this component loads the tiles from my router function.

This works, but the problem is: it is very slow, because OpenSeadragongs loads > 100 tiles per second.

I am searching for a good, fast and safe solution for this problem...

I can change my Amazon OpenSeadragon tiles folder visibility to "public" with a difficult random foldername, but anyone who know this foldername, he can download the photo. That's not a good solution...

Comment: A common solution to supplying non-public S3 assets to clients is to use S3 pre-signed URLs. These allow the bearer to download the asset directly from S3 but are much more secure than hosting assets in a public bucket. The pre-signed URL has an in-built expiration date/time which you dictate.

Comment: Yes I know. I generate pre-signed urls with my router function temoraryUrl(), but that's not a solution for javascript.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand. Can you explain why this is this not a solution for JavaScript?

Comment: What I understand is that you have performance issues which are unrelated to public/private bucket. Does the behavior of `OpenSeadragongs` change when bucket is Public?

Comment: I don't know about SeaDragon specifically, but I would expect pre-signed URLs to perform the same as public S3 URLs.

Comment: The problem is: OpenSeadragons is a fantastic component for zooming in very large photos. When you zoom in, OpenSeadragons loads very very much photos, like 10/01_01.jpg, 10/01_02.jpg, 10/01_03.jpg, etc. etc. This all happens 100% clientside, javascript only. That's why I cannot (serverside) generate pre-signed URL's.

Comment: I presume that you can customize the URLs by writing JS so your JS client could initially request permission-limited AWS credentials from a server (something you provide using AWS Lambda or any other compute) and use those credentials on the client-side to create pre-signed URLs (which is a purely local computation, once you have a set of credentials). You obviously need to solve how to authenticate your client, but you have that problem regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is likely by placing Cloudfront in front our your S3 bucket and switch from presigned URL's to presigned cookies.

The Cloudfront documentation for presigned cookies is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html
It should allow you to basically pre-allow access to all the subphotos for zooming, as long as you use a wildcard character to give access.

The AWS docs on choosing between presigned URLs and presigned cookies: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html
Note that it specifically mentions "**You want to provide access to multiple restricted files, for example, all of the files for a video in HLS format or all of the files in the subscribers' area of a website.**"